# Counting number of functions such that composition is inverse

Tags: functions, permutations

Let  $f :A \to A$, where
$A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. Then number of functions such that
$f(f(f(x)))= x$, for all $x$ belonging to $A$.

I could understand that $f(f(x))$ would be inverse of $f(x)$.
But then how to do counting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is equivalent to find elements of order $3$ in the symmetric group $S_7$ because all of the functions we want are bijective (and so permutations).

If $f$ represents a $3$-cycle, then there are $2{7\choose 3} = 70$ elements. (e.g. $(123),(132)$.)

If $f$ represents a product of two disjoint $3$-cycles, then there are $2{7\choose 3}\cdot 2{4\choose 3}/2 = 280$ such elements. (e.g. $(123)(456)$.)

The trivial $f$ is also an element.

Hence there are $351$ such functions in total.

Comment: no answer is 351

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my previous calculation.@maveric

Comment: could you please explain more?

Comment: i dont have idea about group.

Comment: in 7c3 into 7c4 why 2 muliplied twice .

Comment: I count twice because $(132)$ and $(123)$ are different elements. $(132)$ maps $1$ to $3$, $3$ to $2$ and $2$ to $1$, while $(123)$ maps $1$ to $2$ and so on.

Comment: In your question, every element comes back in three times, so every element lies in an orbit of length $3$ or $1$. That's why I need to count $3$-cycles.

Comment: even first 7c3 why multiply by 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93130/discussion-between-hongyi-huang-and-maveric).

Comment: why cant we have more than 3 elements cycle.